# UIActivityViewController share SVG file

Tags: ios, svg, uiactivityviewcontroller

I try to share SVG file with UIActivityViewController but only available options are Message and Mail. If I choose mail nothing is attached. Is there any way to make this?

Comment: Which application should open your svg file?

Comment: Other applications that support svg files

Comment: which UTI did you use? and also maybe you should use a UIDocumentInteractionController

Comment: I'm using public.svg-image. With UIDocumentInteractionController it works, but I want to make it from my controller

Comment: Can you share how your attaching the file for UIActivityViewController

Comment: I'm making svg string to data
NSData *svgData = [svgString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
            [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[svgData]
                                              applicationActivities:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You should save your string as data to the app temp or documents folder, then use the url as the activity item, the OS can handle it well:

```
extension Data {
/// Data into file
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - fileName: the Name of the file you want to write, remember to include extension.
/// - Returns: Returns the URL where the new file is located in
func toFile(fileName: String) -> URL? {
    var filePath: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
    filePath.appendPathComponent(fileName)

    do {
        try write(to: filePath)
        return filePath
    } catch {
        print("Error writing the file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Then you can do something like:

```
let textData = Data(yourSVGString.utf8)
let uniqueRandomName = String(UUID().uuidString.suffix(4))
let svgURL = textData.toFile(fileName: "\(uniqueRandomName).svg")
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [svgURL], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```